# Create foreign table on file_fdw as non-superuser

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have created a file_fdw extension and a corresponding server as superuser.

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER myserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;

ALTER SERVER myserver OWNER TO nonsuperuser;
```

I want a non-superuser `nonsuperuser` to use this server to create a foreign table

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE test (
   a text NULL,
   b text NULL
)
SERVER myserver
    OPTIONS (filename '/home/me/mycsvfile.csv', format 'csv', header 'true', delimiter ';');
```

Executing this, leads to `only superuser can change options of a file_fdw foreign table

What can I do to enable `nonsuperuser` to create foreign tables? If possible I would not mind declaring the options as super user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only highly privileged users are allowed to access files on the database server, that's why you need high permissions to create a file_fdw foreign table.

From the error message it becomes clear that you are using an old version of PostgreSQL; on more recent versions, the error message would look like:

```
only superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role may specify the filename option of a file_fdw foreign table
```

So, as an alternative to dealing out superuser privileges, you may add the user to the `pg_read_server_files` role.

Upgrade PostgreSQL!